# I give two div the same style on click of a button and they don't behave the same

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have canvas where I can upload pdf file.On click of a button I can create div with image inside that is called **divMark** and I can drag that div on canvas.I made zoom functionality where on click of a button I increase width and height on all four sides for 25px and also I change style left and top of divMark. Original coordinates I store in array I have **xList** for top coordinates and **yList** for left coordinates and each value in **xList** I increase for 12 and **yList** I decrease for 5 then first value form each array I gave to first div second value to second div and so on.

This is code for creating divMark and for zoom functionality:

```
const myImg = document.getElementById("the-canvas");
const divBtn = document.querySelector(".btn-mark");
const zoomOutBtn = document.querySelector(".zoom-out-btn");
const zoomInBtn = document.querySelector(".zoom-in-btn");
let counter = 0;
let showCounter = 1;

divBtn.addEventListener("click", createContent);
zoomInBtn.addEventListener("click", zoomIn);
zoomOutBtn.addEventListener("click", zoomOut);

function createContent() {
var divMark = document.createElement("div");
divMark.classList = `markers mark`;
divMark.id = `${counter}`;

var img = document.createElement("img");
img.classList = "comment";
img.src = "indeksiraj-1.png";
img.alt = "myimage";

var pCounter = document.createElement("p");
pCounter.classList = "p-counter";
pCounter.innerHTML = showCounter;
divMark.appendChild(pCounter);

divMark.appendChild(img);

$(marksCanvas).append(divMark);
divMarks.push(divMark);

counter++;
showCounter++;

window.onload = addListeners();

function addListeners() {
    divMark.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown, false);
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp, false);
}

function mouseUp() {
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", divMove, true);
}

function mouseDown(e) {
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", divMove, true);
}

function divMove(e) {
    var xCord = e.pageX;
    var yCord = e.pageY;
    divMark.style.top = yCord + "px";
    divMark.style.left = xCord + "px";
    divMark.onclick = function () {
        divContent.setAttribute("style", "visibility:visible;");
        console.log(parseInt(divMark.id));

        let index = parseInt(divMark.id);
        xList = removeXListItem(index, xList);

        xList.splice(parseInt(divMark.id), 0, xCord);
        yList.splice(parseInt(divMark.id), 0, yCord);
    };
}
}

function xCordPlus(num) {
return num + 22;
}

function yCordPlus(num) {
return num + -8;
}

function xCordMinus(num) {
return num - 22;
}

function yCordMinus(num) {
return num + 8;
}

function removeXListItem(index, xList) {
xList.splice(index, 1);
return xList;
}


function zoomIn() {
var currWidth = myImg.clientWidth;
if (currWidth == 1000) return false;
else {
    var currWidth = myImg.clientWidth;
    myImg.style.width = currWidth + 100 + "px";
}
xList = xList.map(xCordPlus);
console.log("xList is: " + xList);
yList = yList.map(yCordPlus);

$(".markers").each(function (index) {
    $(this).css({ top: yList[index] + "px", left: xList[index] + "px" });
});
}



function zoomOut() {
var currWidth = myImg.clientWidth;
var currHeight = myImg.clientHeight;
if (currWidth == 800) return false;
else {
    var currWidth = myImg.clientWidth;
    myImg.style.width = currWidth - 100 + "px";
}

xList = xList.map(xCordMinus);
yList = yList.map(yCordMinus);

$(".markers").each(function (index) {
    $(this).css({ top: yList[index] + "px", left: xList[index] + "px" });
});
}
```

My problem is that when I put two **divMarks** one on the left side of canvas other one on the right side **divMark** on the right side works great it moves when I click **zoomInBtn** how is suppose to but **divMark** on the right side it does not work well it moves to much on the right side it not works like **divMark** on the right side.

Here is all code: https://jsfiddle.net/SutonJ/thernqmv/13/

Answer (score 0):

You are making the `zoom-out-btn` class, when hovered, not disabled and active, go down the screen by the length of 12.5% of the size of the html element's font size on line 200 of the CSS in that jsfiddle you posted.

```
.zoom-out-btn:not(:disabled):hover:active { 
    transform: scale(1.05) translateY(0.125rem);
}
```

You are never doing the same for `zoom-in-btn`. Additionally, the css is quite different for the `zoom-in-btn`, so you need to add a transition property to that class if you want the on-hover effect to look smooth.

Comment: CSS zoom-out-btn is not my problem I don't need transition to be smooth I need to fix my problem with moving divMark